# python yahoo weather xml parse works with 2.7.1 but not 2.6.1

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

CITY_ID = '23396898'
TEMP_TYPE = 'c'

WEATHER_URL = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=' + CITY_ID +' &u=' + TEMP_TYPE
WEATHER_NS = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'

dom = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(WEATHER_URL))
ycondition = dom.getElementsByTagNameNS(WEATHER_NS, 'condition')[0]
CURRENT_OUTDOOR_TEMP = ycondition.getAttribute('temp')
print(CURRENT_OUTDOOR_TEMP)
```

This works fine when I run it on a machine running python 2.7.1 but not on a machine running 2.6.1. The problem is the actual number is wrong. I have verified I'm pulling the elements correctly and can get other numeric values without issue. But I run this on 2.7.1 and get 12 as the current celsius temp but run this in 2.6.1 and get 54.

What has me even more confused is it works fine with fahrenheit in both environments. If you put f for TEMP_TYPE it will work fine.  I've confirmed it happens on multiple machines. However they are identical deployments so the issue could be something other than 2.6.1. Can anyone give me any ideas why I'm getting this issue?

Running on Mac OS X in both instances.

edit: problem is with  urllib.urlopen() not working correctly in 2.6 not sure why.

edit:

I've also run this with elementtree with the same results. It appears it may be something specific to this environment but why would it convert it back to fahrenheit. Odd.

```
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

CITY_ID = '23396898'
TEMP_TYPE = 'c'

WEATHER_URL = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=' + CITY_ID +' &u=' + TEMP_TYPE
WEATHER_NS = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0'

rss = parse(urllib.urlopen(WEATHER_URL)).getroot()
ycondition = rss.find('channel/item/{%s}condition' % WEATHER_NS)
print ycondition.get('temp')
```

if you go directly to the url you can see the information directly.

http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=2496543&u=f
http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=2496543&u=c

Comment: 12 degrees celsius is ~54 degress fahrenheit. Also the `temp` element appears to be in the `<yweather:condition ...>` element. http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=23396898&u=c

Comment: thanks. not sure why it would convert to fahrenheit. It pulls the temperature correctly then but is converting it back to fahrenheit. I'd be interested to see if this is happening on another machine with 2.6.1 on it. I doubt it would and thing its something specific to this environment. http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html

Comment: I do see the same issue.  I have both python24 and python27 and I see the same case.

Comment: Another difference I see is in the URL that it retrieves.
`http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Waterloo__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/CAXX0531_f.html` for py 2.4 and ` http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Waterloo__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/CAXX0531_c.html` for py 2.7

For some reason, it is getting information from different sources but the data is the same.  If you go to both the web pages, it shows the same data in the same format.

Comment: It has to be a URL issue. Yahoo defaults to Fahrenheit so it's not getting the full URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for the help. I had a space in the url and it was causing problems.

```
WEATHER_URL = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=' + CITY_ID +' &u=' + TEMP_TYPE
```

Should be

```
WEATHER_URL = 'http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss?w=' + CITY_ID +'&u=' + TEMP_TYPE
```

Thanks for the help @ronak you led me in the right direcion